# How to format a file while moving?

Tags: shell, text-processing, files, awk, mv

I have 2 directories. SOURCE and DESTINATION. I am moving the .csv files from source to destination as

```
mv -f SOURCE/*.csv DESTINATION/
```

While moving, I want to remove the first and last line from each of the file in destination. Please help me with the command.

Comment: Related: [what is the easiest way to remove 1st and last line from file with awk?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15856733/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-remove-1st-and-last-line-from-file-with-awk).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't move a file, AND edit it at the same time, since moving a file doesn't physically move the data (on the same filesystem), it just moves a pointer to the data. You can copy and convert the data, then delete the original file, or you can edit the original file, then move it.

```
cd SOURCE
for i in *.csv
do
 awk 'NR>2{print s} {s=$0}' < "$i" > ../DESTINATION/"${i}"
 rm "${i}"
done
```

If you omit the rm line, it gives you the opportunity to verify that everything was converted the way you want, before you delete the source files.

Comment: Now I see that @stany does not want to **move** the files from SOURCE to DESTINATION, as he says in his question, but wants top **copy** them, and edit them in the process. In that case, simply remove the _rm_ line from my answer. I decided not to edit my answer, because it answers the question asked.

Comment: @terdon, what makes you think that it removes the first 2 lines? That does **exactly** what the OP asked for. I think you should look at that awk code a little bit closer. I actually tested my code before I posted it here, just to make sure I wasn't overlooking something.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I hadn't actually posted that. I'd written it and then realized it was wrong. I blame caching. Anyway, please ignore, deleted now.

Answer (score 3):

```
cd SOURCE
for i in *.csv
do
 sed -i '$d' "$i"
 sed -i '1d' "$i"
 mv "$i" DESTINATION/
done
```

Comment: I usually prefer the syntax: for i in *.csv; do... done ,(rather that `ls *.csv`) so you do not get bothered if you have some ugly space characters in your file name...

Comment: does this change the source file?

Comment: @herbert, I'll try your way :)


Yes. It will first modify the source and the moved it to destination

Comment: i dont want to change the source file :(

Comment: @stany you don't want to change file, but want to remove first and last line ?

Comment: or else do the move first, then édit.

Comment: if you wanna keep an unmodified version, use: `sed -i.bak '$d;1d' $i` it will remove last and first line and make you a copy of your file with the .bak extension

Comment: To remain source files unmodified `for ... do sed -n "$q;2,$w DESTINATION/${i##*/}" $i ; done` or `sed '$d;1d' "$i" >  "DESTINATION/${i##*/}"`